# Get connection options for host by alias in Ansible playbook

Tags: deployment, ansible, ansible-playbook

I've got a role, running against `localhost`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    ...
    - name: Push code to target host
      shell: scp -P "{{ ansible_port }}" "{{ home_dir }}/{{ project }}.tgz" root@{{ target_server }}:/home/teamcity/
```

I run this playbook with target_server env var, which is used in one other subtask as target host:

```
ansible-playbook \
-i 'ansible/hosts' \
--extra-vars "target_server=stage" \
ansible/deliver.yml
```

Is there a way to get connection options for `scp`, describied in `ansible/hosts` by server alias, passed as env var? The goal is not to pass `ansible_port` or other connection options twice, but get from already passed server alias `target_server`.

In other words, if I run playbook `--extra-vars "target_server=stage"`, how can I get `ansible_hostname` and `ansible_port` for host `'stage'` to use as scp connection options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running the playbook against localhost I assume the source files are located there.

You can use more fitting modules to copy the files, for example the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html):

```yaml
- hosts: target_server
  tasks:
  - name: Push code via copy
    copy:
      src: "{{ home_dir }}/{{ project }}.tgz"
      dest: "/home/teamcity/"
```

If you want to extract the archive on the target server you can do that in one step using the [unarchive module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html):

```yaml
  - name: Push code via unarchive
    unarchive:
      src: "{{ home_dir }}/{{ project }}.tgz"
      dest: "/home/teamcity/"
```

If the source files are on a different server, you can use the [synchronize module](http://docs.ansible.com/synchronize_module.html) to copy from server A to B:

```yaml
  - name: Push code from remote server
    synchronize:
      src: "{{ home_dir }}/{{ project }}.tgz"
      dest: "/home/teamcity/"
    delegate_to: src_server
```

If you insist on using the shell module with scp, you can access the variables using the [`hostvars` variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables):

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  - name: Push code to target host
    shell: scp -P "{{ hostvars['target_server']['ansible_port'] }}" "{{ home_dir }}/{{ project }}.tgz" root@{{ hostvars['target_server']['ansible_hostname'] }}:/home/teamcity/
```

Comment: Brilliant and exact answer, thank you! Just everything, what I need.